# Moveit: "Group 'arm' includes joints that have more than 1 DOF

Tags: ros, moveit, joints

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have this error message from ROS when loading the model in the C++ ROS node. All joints in the model have only 1 axis of rotation so this message does not make sense. is there any reason why this message might be showing up?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/254995/moveit:-%22group-%27arm%27-includes-joints-that-have-more-than-1-dof/) by [craigc](https://answers.ros.org/users/29398/craigc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-02-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2017-02-18**:
Could you post your urdf?

**Comment by [craigc](https://answers.ros.org/users/29398/craigc/) on 2017-02-18**:
The code will not post well but the URDF code is hosted at https://github.com/greenpro/sac_description/blob/master/urdf/scorbot_description.xacro

The rest of the description project is at
https://github.com/greenpro/sac_description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First: the error message you quote is actually not coming from MoveIt itself, but from the kinematics plugin you have configured for your `arm` group. MoveIt itself doesn't really care, but plugins like KDL, LMA and others don't support joints with more than a single dof.

As to a possible cause: in `greenpro/sac_config/config/andreas_arm.srdf` ([here](https://github.com/greenpro/sac_config/blob/0d262d324f70140f230ad6361b35d8da40f9ef49/config/andreas_arm.srdf#L13)) you have:

```
<group name="arm">
    <joint name="virtual_joint" />
    ...
</group>
...
<virtual_joint name="virtual_joint" type="planar" parent_frame="odom_combined" child_link="world" />
```

Your `arm` group includes `virtual_joint`, which you have configured as a planar joint. Planar joints combine 2 dof, so I think that is where your error message is coming from.

Btw: the virtual joint is typically not included in any group, as it is the joint that connects your robot / cell to the 'world'.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-02-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-24**:
From [greenpro/sac_config@67d1af6463da688cededec1a0def76129ff7209e](https://github.com/greenpro/sac_config/commit/67d1af6463da688cededec1a0def76129ff7209e) I have the impression that you've solved the problem by removing the virtual joint frome the `arm` group?

**Comment by [craigc](https://answers.ros.org/users/29398/craigc/) on 2017-02-24**:
I solved the problem by remaking the project using the setup assistant and changing the joint to a fixed joint. The removal was from a previous attempt to solve the problem. The configuration is now at https://github.com/greenpro/scorbot_config